# React - Javascript horizontal menu scrolling as you scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a horizontal menu that is moving to the left-right (kind of a spyscroll) as you move through the app.
Currently I have only underline and text colour change because I didn't know how to make it "scroll" as you move down the app... Does anyone have an idea how to do that? Thank you in advance.

Attached image: [Menu and App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG2M8.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Refer this video](https://youtu.be/JMsNslI8KoY)

set active class name for each section in the header and get the scroll value from the event listener and use conditions to apply the active class name

Comment: But I want to scroll them horizontally as you scroll vertically...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would say the most common way of changing an element based on scrolling is to use Intersection observer. Using intersection observer you can specify what should happen when a certain element is not visible/visible/visible partialy.
The second method I can think of is to manually calculate the position of window:

```
window.pageYOffset
```

And set a condition like so:

```
if(window.pageYOffset > XX){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to element which has the vertical scroll.

```
 verticalScrollEl.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
    horizontalScrollEl.scrollLeft = e.target.scrollLeft;
 });
```